# Node app auto reload, auto compile coffee script and auto compile less css

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript, less, v8

does anyone know how can I do this?
I've found nodemon to monitor the folder for changes and restart the node app on every change.
I also want a way to recompile .coffee and .less files automaticaly.

Could anyone give me a hint?

Comment: also, have a look at node-dev -- tend to be my preferred choice (better console log outputs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to use Coffeescript in a Node app? If so just point nodemon to your coffee file, and assuming you have a reasonably modern version of Node it should Just Work:

`nodemon your_node_program_file.coffee`

If you have Coffeescript you need to compile for other purposes (for example you use it on the frontend) you could use [GruntJS](http://gruntjs.com) and a [GruntJS plugin to compile Coffeescript to Javascript](https://npmjs.org/package/grunt-contrib-coffee)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to struggle with Grunt, another option would be to use Foreman (see example [here](https://github.com/mck-/T3/blob/master/Procfile-dev)) which you can start with `make` ([example](https://github.com/mck-/T3/blob/master/Makefile))